# Is it possible to count the number of occurrences of a calculated field's result in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a function that categorizes calls a user has made into 3 categories using this calculation:

```
    IF 0 <= DATEDIFF('dayofyear', [SubmittedDateTime], [CALLDATE]) 
    AND DATEDIFF('dayofyear', [SubmittedDateTime], [CALLDATE]) <= 7 
    THEN "Week After"
    ELSEIF -7 <= DATEDIFF('dayofyear', [SubmittedDateTime], [CALLDATE]) 
    AND DATEDIFF('dayofyear', [SubmittedDateTime], [CALLDATE]) < 0
    THEN "Week Before"
    ELSE "Not within a week"
    END
```

I was wondering if it's possible to count the number of occurrences of a particular outcome of the function on a per user basis in order to then categorize each user based off of the number of occurrences. I'm attempting to use this calculation to do so:

```
    IF { FIXED [SUBID]: COUNT([DateDiff Calc] = 'Week After')} = 1
    THEN "1 Conference User"
    ELSEIF { FIXED [SUBID]: COUNT([DateDiff Calc] = 'Week After') } > 1
    THEN "Multiple Conference User"
    ELSE "0 Conference User"
    END
```

but the COUNT function I'm using is not working properly it seems. It seems that the COUNT function is also counting occurrences of both "Week Before" and "Not within a week" from the first function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the measure part of your LOD expression :

```
 COUNT([DateDiff Calc] = 'Week After')
```

This will just give you count of both times: when your conditions is met and when its not met. [DateDiff Calc] = 'Week After' will return true or false, both will be counted as +1 in the count function.

You could try something like:

```
IF { FIXED [SUBID]: SUM(IF[DateDiff Calc] = 'Week After' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)} = 1 
THEN "1 Conference User" 
...
```